# One line command from Windows cmd to execute WSL 2 command

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to call WSL 2 command from Windows cmd by using only one entry.
Give me correct one-liner example if need to check from Windows cmd if I can ping `8.8.8.8` from WSL 2:

```
bash && ping 8.8.8.8
```

*I know that command it's not working*

Comment: I don't have WSL 2, try `wsl ping 8.8.8.8`.  It should work.

Comment: thank you. that's working